# Editing java file within jar library

Tags: java, jar, decompiler

I need to replace one word (REPLACE with MODULATE) within the StdDraw3D.java file. I have opened the jar jd-gui and am pretty stuck now. I have been looking for videos or websites and cant quite find a way to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have not copy paste the code as i don't need help with code just how to edit or replace the original java file.

[image]
[image: Screenshots]

Comment: aaaaaand how exactly is this related to C#...?

Comment: I removed the c# tag since it doesn't seem relevant.

Answer (score 2):

You have to download the complete source code for StdDraw.jar, update the required java file and rebuild the code again to get the updated jar file. Then use the updated jar in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Steps:- 
1. Download the StdDraw.jar

2. Extract the jar file in folder by right click on it and click on extract.
3. Copy the StdDraw3D.java file and edit and make required changes then compile it again. Then copy the changed class and java files in the above folder.
4. Now again create jar file out of that folder.